# nginx php5-fpm path_info urls and root location

Tags: php, nginx, php-fpm

Hello to all nginx & php gurus

I'm installing dotclear (a blogging software written in PHP) on my debian, and I have a hard time configuring nginx, php5-fpm and php so that :

1. I can use PATH_INFO url rewriting since I'm following Tim Berneer's Lee advice that urls should'nt expose what particular technology you use right now http://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI.html
2. satic-files are **not** parsed by PHP since it's terribly insecure to let `example.org/uploads/image.jpg/index.php` to be sent to PHP
3. have a root location that just works example.com should be rewritten to something like example.com/index.php?start

It seems that until now, I have to choose 2, that's why I'm asking for help here.

So here is my current `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

`server {
   server_name articles.eloge-de-la-folie.fr;
   root /srv/data1/articles.eloge-de-la-folie.fr  ;`

```
index index.php?start ;
location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ @pathinfo ;
         #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$uri?$args;
}
```

# Pretty URLs in dotclear
   # activate PATH_INFO urls in /admin/blog_pref.php
   location @pathinfo {
        rewrite ^ /index.php$uri?$args last; 
   } 
   location = / {
        rewrite ^ /index.php?start last;
   } 
   location ~ ^(.+.php)(/.*)?$ {
            include         fastcgi_params_pathinfo ;
    }

}

I put everything fastcgi related in a separate `/etc/fastcgi_params_pathinfo` config file

```
fastcgi_param   QUERY_STRING        $query_string;
fastcgi_param   REQUEST_METHOD      $request_method;
fastcgi_param   CONTENT_TYPE        $content_type;
fastcgi_param   CONTENT_LENGTH      $content_length;

#fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME     $request_filename;
fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME     $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO               $fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param   REQUEST_URI     $request_uri;
fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_URI        $document_uri;
fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_ROOT       $document_root;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_PROTOCOL     $server_protocol;

fastcgi_param   GATEWAY_INTERFACE   CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_SOFTWARE     nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param   REMOTE_ADDR     $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param   REMOTE_PORT     $remote_port;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_ADDR     $server_addr;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_PORT     $server_port;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_NAME     $server_name;

fastcgi_param   HTTPS           $https;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param   REDIRECT_STATUS     200;


# this is what I changed
fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
fastcgi_index   index.php;
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

Also in `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`, I made sure to uncomment this

```
security.limit_extensions = .php ;
```

What happen currently ?
- example.com/index.php and example.com/post/test are passed to the php interpretor and work
- example.com/css/style.css are not passed to php and works
- but when I go to example.com, the index.php is just downloaded, not interpreted.

My `location = / { configuration here }` is apparently never matched :(

Thanks in advance,

Jean-Michel

Comment: I forgot to say that I have nothing meaningful in the logs

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20131128170008/http://yeti.selfip.net/cms/index.php/post/2013/10/26/Configure-PHP-with-Nginx-only-once-for-several-aliases) you'll find help.
And keep this too:

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME     $request_filename;
```

It's not very elegant, but I don't have a better solution to provide :(

One note, though: When configuring dotclear to use `PATH_INFO`, you still have an `index.php` inside, just as in the URL above (which is hosted by dotclear). There may be a way around this with URL rewrites...

Comment: Can you add more detail to improve this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is the problem

```
index index.php?start ;
location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ @pathinfo ;
         #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$uri?$args;
}
```

Nginx will never find a file with the filename "index.php?start" on the hard drive.  In your location / block you are saying, try to find the URI, which is just /, which is just the root directory, and it finds that.

> My location = / { configuration here } is apparently never matched :(

It is matched, just the first one is matched and not the second one.
Remove the first location / block and the index index.php?start (because I think the latter will never work).